# Dimensions + Name for Launch Screen and icon for iPhone 4 in XCode

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, bundle

I have the Default.png for iPhone 3GS and older models. I was just wondering what is the name of the launch screen for iPhone 4 and what is the name of the icon for iphone 4. I am pretty sure the launch screen is Default@X.png but i cant remember. I do not have an idea of what the icon could be. ALSO, if I dont incorporate the iphone 4 launch screen or icon will the launch screen and icon show up on the iphone anyways, just more blurry? I do not want to get a reject from apple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `@2x` to the name and use 640x960 as resulution for the launch screen.

You can find informations about the Icon dimensions [here](http://www.miralemcebic.de/Miralem_Cebic/Blog/Entries/2010/10/4_Tut_010_%402x_%3D_Retina_Display.html) (German, but the important part is the table with the dimensions)

Answer (score 1):

Please see apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) . This [QA](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) section also is very informative. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html) also..